# Could someone explain why this document.write overwrites the entire page?

Tags: random, overwrite, document.write

Here is the code; javascript

```
function Roll()
     // Results: displays a randomly selected image of a 6-sided die
     {
       var roll;

       roll = RandomInt(1, 6);

       if (roll == 1) {
         document.getElementById("die").src = 
             "die1.gif";
         document.write("<center><p><a href='bad.html'> Enter </a></p></center>");
       }
       else if (roll == 2) {
         document.getElementById("die").src = 
             "die2.gif";
         document.write("<center><p><a href='good.html'> Enter </a></p></center>");
       }
       else if (roll == 3) {
         document.getElementById("die").src = 
             "die3.gif";
         document.write("<center><p><a href='bad.html'> Enter </a></p></center>");
       }
       else if (roll == 4) {
         document.getElementById("die").src = 
             "die4.gif";
         document.write("<center><p><a href='good.html'> Enter </a></p></center>");
       }
       else if (roll == 5) {
         document.getElementById("die").src = 
             "die5.gif";
         document.write("<center><p><a href='bad.html'> Enter </a></p></center>");
       }
       else {
         document.getElementById("die").src = 
             "die6.gif";
         document.write("<center><p><a href='good.html'> Enter </a></p></center>");
       }
     }
```

And here is the Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/seymorevenue/TcNF7/ (though document.write doesn't seem to work there, and the dice images arn't up)
I don't think I really understand the Document.write statement, and is there a better method? All I want to do is roll a die and display a link based on the result. Thanks for any help

Comment: See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fdocument.write#Notes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [document.write() overwriting the document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19941866/document-write-overwriting-the-document)

Answer (score 1):

I think document.write() makes significant changes to a website and it is rarely used after clicking on a button, but rather when a site loads.

Instead, use something like this:

```
document.getElementByID('YourOutputDiv').innerHTML = 'Text to display on website';
```

Comment: Thank you Momro it worked (as soon as I de-capitalized the D in getElementById) This does make more sense, and I will refrain from breaking my pages with useless document.write statements. Much appreciated