# Show popup when adblock is active

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this simple code to detect if adblock is active

```
<script>
(function(){
 var test = document.createElement('div');
 test.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
 test.className = 'adsbox';
  document.body.appendChild(test);
 window.setTimeout(function() {
  if (test.offsetHeight === 0) {
  alert("active");      
} else {
 alert("not active");
}
test.remove();
}, 100);
})();
```

This works fine so far.

Instead of display a alert message, I need a jquery popup. Therefore I changed the above code to:

```
<script>
(function(){
 var test = document.createElement('div');
 test.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
 test.className = 'adsbox';
 document.body.appendChild(test);
 window.setTimeout(function() {
if (test.offsetHeight === 0) {
 showmessage();      
}
test.remove();
}, 100);
})();
</script>
```

Without this function

```
showmessage();
```

works perfect.

When showmessage(); is inside this function, the popup doesnt come up. Instead the showmessage(); content is displayed on the website without css and not as a popup. I think this has something todo with the timeout function. But without this timeout, the detetection does not work in firefox.

Content from showmessage();

```
function showmessage(){
document.write("<div id=\"boxes\">");
document.write("  <div id=\"dialog\" class=\"window\">");
document.write("  <div style=\"display: none; opacity: 0.8;\" id=\"mask\">
<\/div>");
 document.write("<\/div></div>");

setTimeout(
function() {
    var id = '#dialog';

    //Get the screen height and width
    var maskHeight = $(document).height();
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
    $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

    //transition effect     
    $('#mask').fadeIn(500); 
    $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.9);  

    //Get the window height and width
    var winH = $(window).height();
    var winW = $(window).width();

    //Set the popup window to center
    //$(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
    $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

    //transition effect
    $(id).fadeIn(1000);     

//if close button is clicked
$('.window .close').click(function (e) {
    //Cancel the link behavior
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#mask').hide();
    $('.window').hide();
});     

//if mask is clicked
/*$('#mask').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.window').hide();
});     */

}, 200);
}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: You don't want to use `document.write` which overwrite all page's content if called once page is loaded.  Basically, just set a `div` hidden by default and show it if user use any ads blocker

Comment: It doestn matter aslong the popup comes up. showmessage() works fine. thank you

Comment: `showmessage() works fine` No, it doesn't... It doesn't work as you expect it to work. See again th reason here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19941866/document-write-overwriting-the-document

Comment: Ok, thank you, I see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the prepend method to body and then set the popup HTML string into the method . :

```
function showmessage(){
        var jQueryPopupHTML = "<div id='boxes'><div id='dialog' class='window'> <div style='display: none;  opacity: 0.8;' id='mask'></div></div></div>"
        $( "body" ).prepend(jQueryPopupHTML);

    setTimeout(
    function() {
        var id = '#dialog';

        //Get the screen height and width
        var maskHeight = $(document).height();
        var maskWidth = $(window).width();

        //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
        $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

        //transition effect     
        $('#mask').fadeIn(500); 
        $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.9);  

        //Get the window height and width
        var winH = $(window).height();
        var winW = $(window).width();

        //Set the popup window to center
        //$(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
        $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

        //transition effect
        $(id).fadeIn(1000);     

    //if close button is clicked
    $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#mask').hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });     

    //if mask is clicked
    /*$('#mask').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });     */

    }, 200);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works perfect. Would you please explain me in short my error? Also your code has no fade in anymore. Is it possible to add this too?

Comment: After the page has finished loading, `document.write` cannot add more content to the page - instead it completely overwrites the existing content.

Instead, you should use methods like [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [`node.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) to add new content to the page (or jQuery's [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)/[`prepend`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)). This also gives you control over *where* the content is added to the DOM tree.

Comment: tx for the explantion. I understand. Do you know why the fade in effect is not working anymore?

Comment: ok found it. 
$(jQueryPopupHTML).hide().prependTo("body").fadeIn("slow");