# How do I call the JavaScript function properly?

Tags: javascript, html, function, call

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>JavaScript Example</title>
<script>

function displayString() {
    return "<h1>Main Heading</h1>"
}

displayString();
document.write("Execute during page load from the head<br>");
</script>
</head>

<body>

<script>
    document.write("Execute during page load from the body<br>");
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

So this is my problem. No matter where I put the displayString(), the h1 just never seems to show up on the browser. Can anybody please help me see where I am wrong? I am new to JavaScript. Oh, and what I am trying to do is to call the function.

Comment: Wow, two upvote for this question..!!

Comment: Yeah it's almost as if someone had asked for upvotes, maybe by people they know or those answering? Though that would be against the rules so, no, couldn't be that?!

Comment: You’re “properly” calling the function—you’re just not doing anything with the function’s return value, e.g. using it in a call to document.write to add it as content to the document.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write the returned String to the `document`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>JavaScript Example</title>
<script>

function displayString() {
    return "<h1>Main Heading</h1>"
}

document.write(displayString());
document.write("Execute during page load from the head<br>");
</script>
</head>

<body>

<script>
    document.write("Execute during page load from the body<br>");
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Don't use `document.write`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19941866/document-write-overwriting-the-document)

Answer (score 1):

> No matter where I put the `displayString()`, the `h1` just never seems to
>   show up on the browser.

If you wish to add *a new element* to a document, several approaches are available:

- `document.write` ([effectively deprecated](https://love2dev.com/blog/documentwrite/))
- `.innerHTML` (sometimes useful, but can be slow)
- `DOM API` - recommended approach

The recommended approach is to use the **DOM API**.

**DOM** stands for *Document Object Model*. Essentially it's the markup of your document represented as a tree-like structure of nodes. There are many DOM API functions which allow you to:

- add
- remove
- append
- prepend
- insert
- update

new DOM nodes.

Any DOM node may be added, removed or updated, including:

- parent elements
- child elements
- sibling elements
- element attributes
- `ids`, `classNames`, `classLists`
- custom `data-*` attributes
- text nodes

Here is an example:

```js
function displayMainHeading () {
  
  let mainHeading = document.createElement('h1');
  mainHeading.textContent = 'Main Heading';
  document.body.prepend(mainHeading);
}

displayMainHeading();
```

```html
<p>Paragraph 1</p>

<p>Paragraph 2</p>
```

---

### Further Reading

This is a good primer to get you started:

- [A Beginners Guide To DOM Manipulation by Iqra Masroor](https://dev.to/iqramqra/a-beginners-guide-to-dom-manipulation-45bk)